# How to use Azure App Service Authentication for a Angular 4 app?

Tags: angular, azure, iis

I have deployed a Angular 4 app to Azure. The app uses a API and the api is also deployed to azure, in the sub folder named 'V1'. The Angular app is deployed in the root.

Next I have enabled 'App Service Authentication' in the Azure portal. Now, when I want to access my site I see Azure's login page where I need to enter my e-mail address. When I enter my e-mail address, I get redirected to `/.auth/login/aad/callback`. On this page I get the error

`You do not have permission to view this directory or page.`

I have tried to add a web.config with this content, but that doesn't help:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <rewrite>
      <rules>
        <rule name="AngularJS" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url="^(?!.*(.bundle.js|.bundle.map|.bundle.js.gz|.bundle.css|.bundle.css.gz|.png|.jpg|.ico)).*$" />
          <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
          </conditions>
          <action type="Rewrite" url="/"  appendQueryString="true" />
        </rule>
      </rules>
    </rewrite>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

In the angular I use the azure URL to access my API, so I get my data from: `https://my-site.azurewebsites.net/V1/xxx`

What do I need to do, so I can use the App Service Authentication from Azure?

Comment: The best way to figure out what might be going wrong is to enable **Application Logging** and then look at the warning messages contained in the log files (or in the log stream). More instructions can be found here: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-enable-diagnostic-log/. Just to rule out stale login information, make sure to try this after opening a new private/incognito browser session.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. For some reason it does work now. I have removed the service app, created a new one and applied logging. For some reason it all works as expected. I also removed the web.config, so I didn't need that.